# How do I reliably run a PHP script with a long run time triggered using a cron job

Tags: php, web-scraping, server, cron, firewall

I want to crawl 3,000 URLs on a competitor's site to scrape a price value. I don't want to over-load their servers or otherwise trigger any firewall so first basic measure is to spread these 3,000 requests over the period of a week.

I have code set up like this:

```
set_time_limit(0);

foreach ($links as $link) {

    // crawl price from link

    // save price to database

    // 200 second delay before next crawl
    sleep(200);

}
```

I'm triggering this script using a cron job that runs at midnight every week.

The line `set_time_limit(0)` should override the max-execution time but I've read that scripts triggered by a cron-job are not subject to standard execution time limitations.

The problem is, for this script to run for a week I assume the server has to be completely stable with no down-time otherwise the crawl will fail.

How can I ensure this, and in the case there is down-time, then restart the crawl automatically from the point it failed? Is a week too long for a script to run? Otherwise I can condense it to a few hours, but still, there is enough time there for the script to be interrupted and I'm interested in the scenario where it is interrupted, how to handle this and complete the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you set one in the `php.ini`, there is no max_execution_time when using the CLI which you are when running a CRON.

Also if you are crawling each URL only once, and the url's are all different (not 200 all on the same site) then waiting between each seperate crawl is not necessary as the URL's are not linked or talking with each other

If you want to restart a script, then all you need to do is write a "where I got to" to a file or the database. then whenever the script starts it checks for a restart point and goes from there. Remember to delete the restart file/db when the script completes so the next time you run the script it starts from the first url again.

Comment: Makes sense, to increase the cron-job request rate and batch: e.g.

Cron is called every hour
It crawls X number (e.g. 10) of urls in an hour, saves to database and logs the url in a file
Then next batch crawl, if the url is in the file, it skips until finds the first URL that is not in the file and continues from there
When no more URLs in the file then the file is cleared and a crawl_log is generated to let know the whole batch was crawled

Comment: If they are all seperate domains, just process through all 3000 in one go. It will probably take minutes rather than hours.

Comment: Ah I should have been clear, they are all the same domain. 3000 different products on the same domain, hence the need for more measures to avoid overloading server resources or firewalls.

Comment: Ahh, that makes the need for a wait, but 200 seconds between each call is a lot longer than necessary I would say, try 10 seconds, that should be enough. Although, none of this will stop a site that checks how many requests a user is making per [period] from considering you a thief and blocking your IP

Comment: Right! Really appreciate the responses. 200 was an example, I've got it set at 10s, but either way, 4 hours vs 1 week, the script could get interrupted, so batching and calling the cron more often based on a temporary log file seems far more robust. I'm randomising the delay by calling `sleep(rand(7,12))` currently too.

Comment: It is best in these situations to apply to use their API if they have one, and if they dont, they probbaly dont want you crawling their price list and will have measures in place to spot you and block you

Comment: Got it, yes that would be ideal, however as a competitor, they likely wouldn't want to share their feed. Their pricing is publicly available on their website, I just want to aggregate it and it's up to them to detect, hence my evasive measures :-)